# CiviMember payment- message template

Tags: civicontribute, civimail, civimember

When someone renews their membership using Pay Later, they get the Membership Receipt Online message as an Invoice from message templates.

The contribution is pending.

In the backend, if the contribution is then updated to Complete, they get the Contributions - Receipt (off-line) message.

What I want them to get is the Membership Receipt Online message as a Receipt.

Is there a cunning way of doing that?

Comment: Actually I just discovered this setting /civicrm/admin/setting/preferences/contribute Enable Tax and Invoicing which solves most of this problem.

Comment: Hi Tony - indeed - if you toggle the "Send Receipt?" option when recording a payment in the back office, this will trigger the Contributions - Receipt (off-line) message regardless of the original source of the contribution - another alternative (if you have access to a developer) would be to create an extension that will send the desired system workflow message based on the origin of the contribution (i.e. if contribution is membership payment and online contribution page is not null, send receipt as configured in the "Thank-you and Receipting" tab of the contribution page).

Comment: If you prefer the use of invoicing as you indicated, then you should post that as your response and accept it :-).